# Creating Xamarin Forms Project with Visual Studio2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I want to new Xamarin.Forms project but visual studio is not responding.
I'm click File > New Project > Cross Platform > Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native) > Xamarin.Forms & Portable and click to OK.
Visual studio start creating project but is not completed.
It's been 25 minutes. It started to happen after this last update. What is the problem ?
[image]

Comment: it happened to me last night, there was a hidden dialog behind this one asking for windows edition to use, after choosing it it finished..

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I just moved around all windows and I saw dialog that I should have interacted with. I am not sure if you're having the same exact problem.

Comment: I can not see window like that.

Comment: Then it could be another problem.. Force it to stop, restart Visual Studio, Restart PC and try again..

Comment: I try this but not solved.

Comment: Also I want to open existing Xamarin.Forms project but when solution loading visual studio is locking.

Comment: I face the same problem since this morning

Comment: If go to existing project folder and delete .vs (hidden) folder and click to your project .sln file, visual studio is opening the project. But if open visual studio and select your solution file (File > Open > Your Project.sln) visual studio is locking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem!

1. First install java jdk 8u121 x64 (for windows 10 x64)
2. Open VS and go to Tools > Options > Xamarin
3. Change Android Jdk location (eg: C:\Program Files\
   Java\jdk1.8.0_121)
4. Restart visual studio
5. Create new xamarin.forms project (file > new > project > cross
   platform)

I'm created project as successfuly..